# Placement new with different types

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, placement-new

Is it well-defined behavior in C++ Standards to use placement new with different types and then `delete[]` the buffer of old type? Assume the alignment of `a` and size of the buffer pointed by `a` meet the requirement for the placement new of `B`, and `B` either has trivial destructor or we don't depend on any side effect of `b`'s destructor call.

```
class A {...};
class B {...};

A *a = new A[16];
B *b = ::new (static_cast<void*>(a)) B;

b->xxx = 123; //use b

delete[] a;
```

My understanding is when `delete[] a`, it will call the destructor of `A`. But now the memory for `a` is occupied by object of `B`. Is this well-defined behavior if `a` has: (a) trivial destructor (b) non-trivial destructor ?

How about if we access `a` after the placement new? Does this violate strict aliasing rule?

```
class A {...};
class B {...};

A *a = new A[10];
B *b = ::new (static_cast<void*>(a)) B;

a->yyy = 456;
```

Comment: This is undefined behavior, that will likely [result in demons flying out of your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Are all of them UB? Just because placement new with different types?

Comment: More likely than not. Perhaps if the two classes are PODs, and have the same size, maybe one can argue that it's not UB. However, for all practical purposes, I would not waste time trying to figure out whether it might not be UB, and just write it off as such, and move on.

Comment: `B *b = ::new (static_cast<void*>(a)) B;` is OK, I believe, per **[basic.life]/1**: "The lifetime of an object `o` of type `T` ends when ...the storage which the object occupies is ... reused". `delete[] a` however exhibits undefined behavior, by way of accessing an object whose lifetime has ended.

Comment: Before we can even discuss the `delete[]` part, you need to fix some issues: size issue, alignment issue.

Comment: @curiousguy After allocating with new the memory is suitably aligned, isn't it?